# ScalaCheck: generate arbitrary functions with arbitrary types

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I have implemented the following function:

```
/**
  * Returns a function h , which is the composition of the functions f and g.
  */
def compose[A, B, C](g: B => C, f: A => B): A => C = f.andThen(g)
```

And I'm trying to test it with [ScalaCheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/documentation.html). I could generate the following tests, which compile and pass:

```
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class ComposeSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with PropertyChecks {

  "Compose" should "return a function h , which is the composition of the 
functions f and g" in {

    forAll { (a: Int, g: Int => Int, f: Int => Int) =>
      compose(g, f)(a) should be(g(f(a)))
    }

    forAll { (a: String, g: Double => Int, f: String => Double) =>
      compose(g, f)(a) should be(g(f(a)))
    }
  }
}
```

But, as you see, I'm generating arbitrary functions with defined types, and also matching the type of the parameter `a` with the type of the input of the function `f`. What I want to do would be something like this:

```
forAll { (a: A, g: B => C, f: A => B) =>
  compose(g, f)(a) should be(g(f(a)))
}
```

But I don't know the syntax for that, nor if it's possible. Could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [scalatest website](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks) has this to say about `forAll`:

> An implicit `Arbitrary` generator and `Shrink` object needs to be supplied
>   for The `forAll` method will pass each row of data to each parameter
>   type. ScalaCheck provides many implicit `Arbitrary` generators for
>   common types such as `Int`, `String`, `List[Float]`, etc., in its
>   `org.scalacheck.Arbitrary` companion object. So long as you use types
>   for which ScalaCheck already provides implicit `Arbitrary` generators,
>   you needn't worry about them. Same for `Shrink` objects, which are
>   provided by ScalaCheck's `org.scalacheck.Shrink` companion object. Most
>   often you can simply pass a property function to `forAll`, and the
>   compiler will grab the implicit values provided by ScalaCheck.

So unfortunately you can't use `forAll` to check every possible type, because there are no implicit `Arbitrary` and `Shrink` objects for every possible type. It seems pretty impossible to generate arbitrary objects of any type.

The best you could do would be something like:

```
def checkComposeForAll[A : Arbitrary : Shrink, B : Arbitrary : Shrink, C : Arbitrary : Shrink]() = {
  forAll { (a: A, g: B => C, f: A => B) =>
    compose(g, f)(a) should be(g(f(a)))
  }
}

checkComposeForAll[Int, Int, Int]()
checkComposeForAll[String, String, String]()
checkComposeForAll[List[Int], Double, Int]()
// ... etc, check a bunch of types ...
```